# SmoothDivScroll's "running ticker" only scrolls once

Tags: javascript, jquery, news-ticker

My problem today is that the running ticker only scrolls once. The "makeMeScrollable"  contains the text that should be scrolling infinitely but literally only scrolls until the end of the text. Any idea what might be causing this? Firebug shows no issues

Here's my code:

This is in the head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            autoScrollingMode: "always",
            autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight",
            autoScrollingStep: 1,
            autoScrollingInterval: 15
        });

        $("#makeMeScrollable").bind("mouseover", function () {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
        });

        $("#makeMeScrollable").bind("mouseout", function () {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is in the body:

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <p>this contains very long text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, or more specifically, I did some better reading. It turns out that if the different elements each aren't as long as the scrolling bar, they won't get enough time to swap out and therefore the scroller will stop.

I've just increased each text's length and it works perfectly now.